# References inside factory_girl factories don't work properly

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, factory-bot

```
Factory.define :person do |p|
  p.first_name { User.generate_activation_code(6) }
  p.last_name { User.generate_activation_code(6) }
  p.username { "p#{first_name}_#{last_name}" }
  p.email { "#{username}@mail.com" }
  p.password { "password" }
  p.password_confirmation { "password" }
end
```

Gives this error:

> undefined local variable or method
>   `first_name' for main:Object
>   (NameError)
>   ./test/factories/user_factories.rb:4
>   ./features/step_definitions/generic_steps.rb:3
>   ./features/step_definitions/generic_steps.rb:2:in`
>   each'
>   ./features/step_definitions/generic_steps.rb:2:in
>   `/^these (.+) records$/'
>   features/transaction_import.feature:7:in`
>   Given these person records'

Here's my configuration (Ruby 1.8.7)

```
Using cucumber (0.10.0) 
Using cucumber-rails (0.3.2) 
Using factory_girl (1.3.3) 
Using railties (3.0.3) 
Using factory_girl_rails (1.0.1) 
Using rails (3.0.3) 
Using rspec-core (2.4.0) 
Using rspec-expectations (2.4.0) 
Using rspec-mocks (2.4.0) 
Using rspec (2.4.0) 
Using rspec-rails (2.4.1) 
Using webrat (0.7.3)
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a `Person` class? Looks like it should be `User` instead:

```
Factory.define :person, :class => User do |p|
```

Documentation for dependent attributes:

- http://rdoc.info/github/thoughtbot/factory_girl/master/file/README.md#Dependent_Attributes

Comment: I do have a person class. The docs helped. Thanks for that. It's working again now.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change your line:

```
 p.username { "p#{first_name}_#{last_name}" }
```

to

```
p.username {|x| "#{x.first_name}_#{x.last_name}" }
```

That worked for me.